# Fade out div upon element scroll not window position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the heading fading out according to the scroll position, however I would like to attach the fadeout to when the user scrolls to the sticky navigation bar to create a better effect.

I tried the following but no luck!

```
<script>
     $(".l-subheader.at_bottom").scroll(function() {
     $(".l-titlebar-content").css("opacity", 1 - $(".l-subheader.at_bottom").scrollTop() / 220);
     });
</script>
```

Should be pretty straight forward but I'm a JS novice!

http://scottdavy.co.uk/our-care-plans/
http://scottdavy.co.uk/our-pricing/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, you should check value to be not less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the header becomes `position:fixed;` then apply the fade effect.

```
<script>
     $(".l-subheader.at_bottom").scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).css('position') == 'fixed' )
        {
           $(".l-titlebar-content").css("opacity", 1 - $(".l-subheader.at_bottom").scrollTop() / 220);
        }

     });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. I tried your code but it didnt work?

Comment: My bad. Had some typos. Try it again now. `if( $(this).css('position') == 'fixed' )`

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following Demo... Smooth Scroll Header & Subheader

https://jsfiddle.net/pratikgavas/D3DDp/38/

JS Code:-

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#Header").height()) {
 $("#Header").fadeOut(500);
 $("#SubHeader").css('top','0px');
  }else {
    $("#Header").fadeIn(500);
 $("#SubHeader").css('top','100px');
}
```

});

Comment: Implemented this but the effect needs to be in relation to the scroll not just activating a fadeOut upon scroll to an element, it has to be both.